# Ubuntu Server 20.04: "working init not found" — 18.04 unstalls OK

Tags: server, system-installation

When attempting to install Server 20.04 on an old Dell machines (AMD X2, 512MB RAM), the live/installation kernel stops with the message "no working init found."  I tried burning the ISO image to DVD and to USB thumb drive, and both produce the same results.  [I did have to enabled the "noapic" option.]

I downloaded the Server 18.04 .iso image, and it installed fine [I told it not to upgrade the installer].

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Is the AMD X2 just too old for 20.04?

Not enough RAM?

Comment: Had the same problem installing XUbuntu Desktop 20.04 and/or 20.04.1 ( with 18.04 -- 18.04.5 installers working just fine ) on an EliteOne 800 G1 with 16 G of RAM ; so RAM / CPU does not look like a key issue here

Comment: PS. I have ended up installing 18.04 and then immediately upgrading to 20.04 via `do-release-upgrade` ( see e.g. [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/) ) -- and it seems to boot normally